# How to know the count of all reviewed tasks

Tags: support, review-queues, badges

There is a badge "Reviewer" awarded for 250 review tasks. How can I know the count of my reviewed tasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are in a review task, there is a number count and a gauge showing progress toward the next milestone in the upper right.

[image: Review Task Count]

As you can see, I've completed 63 review tasks for this particular category and that is roughly 25% of the way toward the 250 task <kbd>Reviewer</kbd> badge milestone.

You can get to any of these review tasks (even ones closed for the day) by clicking [review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review) in the upper right then [recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) of the review task category you are interested in.

Comment: Should be more freehand...

Comment: @nicael - TBPH, my freehand arrows would likely get my post flagged.